# Replacing with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, joptionpane, hashset

How do I remove duplicated numbers and ask the user to add new numbers to replace the duplicated ones? Let's say the user asks for `5` numbers: `6, 7, 8, 7, 9` using the code I made, the output is `Number 7 was duplicated in position 3`

Now what I need help with, is asking the user to add a new number to replace that 7 so there wouldn't be anymore duplicates.

So I want the entire output to be `Your numbers without duplicates:` and it would print the numbers that were input without any duplications.

The order in which they are entered are important to me because I want to keep testing out ArrayList and try not to confuse myself. 
This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int opt = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers?");
        for (int i=0 ; i < opc ; i++) {
        al.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which numbers?")));
        }

        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
        for (Integer d : al){
            if (s.add(d) == false)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number " + d + " was duplicated in position " + al.lastIndexOf(d));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Replace new number"); //This is where I would like to replace the numbers if possible
            }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Your numbers without duplicates: "); //This is where it would print
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I'm sorry if it doesn't make any sense to you. I have a very hard time explaining what I mean. But I tried explaining everything I needed with detail.

Comment: I guess you need ArrayList.set() method... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_set.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need ArrayList.set() method.

```
   for (Integer d : al){
                while (s.add(d) == false){ //replace if with while to keep looking for duplicate
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number " + d + " was duplicated in position " + al.lastIndexOf(d));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Replace new number"); 


//      al.set(d,[set the new value here]);
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `s.add(d)` and checking for `false`, and then trying to replace the duplicate number, you should check duplicates using `s.contains(d)`. This won't add the number to the list and when the user gives another non duplicate number, you can add that to the list.